# How to prevent print queue window from closing

Tags: windows, printing, printer, queue

I need to monitor an old printer and in order to do so, I open the print queue via "control printers" panel and select the printer but unfortunately, this window just closes itself after a few minutes. How can I prevent this so that it stays open?

I'm on Windows 10 21H1.

Comment: When I open the dialog via Devices and Printers, right-click printer, See what's printing, then the dialog stays up.

Comment: no, the window just disapperars for me after a while without any prints coming through. As I said, I need to monitor just that. It has to stay open in idle on a second screen forever until a print shows up and that I will then notice.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a workaround to access the queue more readily, when the queue CPL closes:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and enter "devices and pri".
- Select **Devices and Printers**.
- Right-click the printer to monitor.
- Select **Create shortcut** and have it made on the Desktop.
- When you need to monitor the queue, or if the dialog has closed,

  - Double-click the shortcut.
  - If more detail is needed, click on ***n* document(s) in queue**.

Comment: Thanks. Instantly re-opening it is at least better than hoping for a real solution with windows...